# locate template inside folder with an eventListener

Tags: symfony, event-listener, device-detection

*For info, the project i'm currently working on is on Symfony 2.3*

I have an event listener called `DeviceListener` checking my user device. (it uses the [MobileDetect](http://mobiledetect.net/) class)

I must point to a folder where there is templates affiliated with that device (mobiles as an example)

At the moment my eventlistener works and can see if my user is on a smartphone or on desktop and can locate my `Mobile` folder. But couldn't make up to the template.

**Here is my working code in the listener**

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;


use Mobile_Detect;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class DeviceListener
{

    /**
     * Twig Loader
     * @var \Twig_Loader_Filesystem
     */
    protected $loader;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * DeviceListener constructor.
     * @param \Twig_Loader_Filesystem $loader
     */
    public function __construct(\Twig_Loader_Filesystem $loader, Session $session)
    {
        $this->loader = $loader;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * @param GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $device = $event->getRequest()->headers->get('User-Agent');
        $class = new Mobile_Detect();
        $mobile = $class->isMobile($device);

        $path_mobile = sprintf('%s/../Resources/views/Mobile', __DIR__);

        if ($mobile) {
            $this->loader->prependPath($path_mobile);
        }
    }
}
```

**and the service.yml I setted up:**

```
app.device_listener:
            class: AppBundle\EventListener\DeviceListener
            arguments:
                - @twig.loader.filesystem
                - @session
            tags:
                - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest}
```

As you can see i'm using `onKernelRequest` but I guess that using `onKernelView` might be a better solution.

And for test purpose I created in my `Resources/views` my Mobile folder containing templates for mobile devices.

```
AppBundle
    |
     -Resources
       |
       - views
         |
         - Mobile
         | |
         | - index.html.twig
         - someView.html.twig
         - someView.html.twig
```

**My template**

```
{% extends '@AppBundle/layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <p>This template is exclusively for mobile !</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The view event is not going to help.  It only fires if the controller action returns null.  You are trying to dynamically add a twig path based on a request.  Normally that sort of stuff is compiled.  Not sure if you can even do it.

Comment: mmmm I see... So the redirection actually works but no idea on how to actually get to the template? The code you have here works to locate the `Mobile` folder if you wonder